# Is there a way to have multiple HTML elements that occupy the same on-screen position natively respond to mouse events?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an application that can have multiple interactive sibling elements positioned at the same coordinates and having the same size. I'm trying to make them all react natively to pointer events, i.e. trigger a CSS `:hover` state, but obviously only the top one reacts and blocks the reaction for all the elements below it. None of the CSS `pointer-events` settings seem to tackle this particular situation.

Is there a way to have *all* of the elements react to the pointer event without having to add mouse event listeners on a layer above them all and trigger the reactions via JS code and messing around with `elementsFromPoint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to have multiple HTML elements that occupy the same on-screen position natively respond to mouse events. When multiple elements occupy the same on-screen position, the element that appears on top will receive the mouse event, and the other elements will be blocked from receiving it. This is due to the nature of how mouse events are handled in HTML and CSS.

One possible solution to your problem is to use a single element to represent all of the interactive sibling elements, and use CSS to visually separate them. You can use CSS to apply different styles to different regions of the element, and use pseudo-elements or child elements to represent the different interactive regions. This way, you can still have multiple interactive regions that occupy the same on-screen position, but they will all be part of a single element that can natively respond to mouse events.

Another option is to use JavaScript to handle the mouse events and trigger the appropriate reactions for each of the interactive sibling elements. You can use the elementFromPoint method to determine which element is under the mouse cursor, and then trigger the appropriate reactions for that element. This approach requires more coding and can be less efficient than using native mouse event handling, but it can work if you need to have multiple interactive elements occupying the same on-screen position.